# How do I replace the hamburger icon of a drawer with a CircleAvatar in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile-application

I am trying to replicate this.

[image: This is the the sample image]

Comment: Use "leading" propery of appBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:Text('hi'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.accessible),
          onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
        ),
      ),
);
```

There you go.. I will work.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Vinay, it helped